# Can't push to Git, due to binary files

Tags: git, github, binaryfiles, command-line-interface

So I've been having issues pushing to my master branch that ive been working due to some binary video files. The files were too large when I tried to push them the first time. So I removed them out of the directory of the project I was working on. But now when I try to push ever since that first initial push and it returns me this error message.

```
Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 326.34 MiB | 639.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 39 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: b7371dc6457272213ca1f568d9484c49
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File themes/SomeFile/uploads/me_582610_mountain-river.mov is 315.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To git@github.com:UserName/Project.git
```

The file it says is too large and seems to still be there somehow isn't actually there at all in my directory or even on my computer. I deleted it completely. What is the problem here? This is my first time ever having issues with this. I went to the referenced Git site for support, https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/ , and ran the `git rm --cached me_582610_mountain-river.mov` and it returns me the message `fatal: pathspec 'me_582610_mountain-river.mov' did not match any files`

Please any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably have the file in an older commit.  You need to `git rebase -i` or `git filter-branch` to get rid of it.  There are a lot of examples on SO of this.

Comment: I ended up just running `git log` found the commit I added the video files. Copied the commit code which was a string of a bunch of numbers and letters. ran `git reset b876a979bba795150fe7dc8c8089b01eb51e4d71` and it removed those video files completely and I didn't loose any of the work from any of the other commits that came after. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Alas, I believe all you've done is move the pointer to the current head back to the commit prior to your large checkin. Unless the size of your .git folder (may be hidden) has decreased by > 315MB, the large binary blob is still in your repo.

Comment: @RichTurner I don't think so. If that was the case I wouldn't have been able to push, and I was able to and had no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, by default, **everything you commit to git remains in your repo - even if you "delete" it in a later commit**.

One of GIT's weaknesses (along with other DVCS') is that it doesn't handle large binary files very well. Many teams/people wanting to version lots of large binary files prefer centralized VCS' like [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/), [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), etc. where one has greater control over what part of a repo one downloads and how many versions of prior commits one persists in a repo.

To your problem: You have a repo into which you've previously committed a large binary file. Even though you subsequently "removed" it from your repo, **the file remains**. To fully delete it from your repo, you'll have to do some surgery, physically destroying the original commit in which the file was added, and then rewriting every subsequent commit in your repo!

As per the [GIT Documentation on removing objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Removing-Objects) (**emphasis** mine):

> There are a lot of great things about Git, but one feature that can cause issues is the fact that a git clone downloads the entire history of the project, including every version of every file. This is fine if the whole thing is source code, because Git is highly optimized to compress that data efficiently. However, **if someone at any point in the history of your project added a single huge file, every clone for all time will be forced to download that large file, even if it was removed from the project in the very next commit**.

The solution to your problem is not a simple process, is destructive (in that it basically rewrites every commit after the commit in which you included the offending file(s)) and is pretty well documented in the above link which I encourage you to read several times and practice on a local copy of your tree before updating your official tree.

**Proceed with care!**

> If you do this immediately after an import, before anyone has started to base work on the commit, you’re fine — otherwise, you have to notify all contributors that they must rebase their work onto your new commits.

Frankly, when I did this a year-or-so ago with a repo of my own (i.e. not shared with anyone else), I chose to copy my current codebase to a new folder and create a new GIT repo from it rather than try to rewrite all my history, packfiles, etc. Losing the history wasn't a major issue for me at the time.

Good luck!

Comment: So if what your saying is true. Then if I'm 4 commits ahead of when I added the actual video files then I will lose all the work that I committed after I added those video files?

Comment: No - it just means that you have to destroy the original operation that stored the large file in your repro and then rewrite the history of each of the subsequent 4 commits you've made since.

Answer (score 1):

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD`

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what that command does and the ramifications for the repository history.

Answer (score 1):

This least scary trick did work all the time for me ->

1. Find out which files you have modified in this project (git status)
2. Backup your current cloned dir
3. Delete the cloned project
4. Create a new clone
5. Copy over the modified files to the newly cloned dir

Then git commit and git push and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at *bfg*. (https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)
It's the easiest way to remove that large file. But the implications with doing this mentioned in the other comments still apply!